# Filling Matrix with data points

Tags: c++, c, opencv

In openCV there's a function called FindHomography which takes MATRICES as input.

I have data points representing the location of the features in a frame. I want to put these data points in a Matrix using C++ or C.
I want to put them in 2d array, which these features represent x and y location.

Please can you suggest how to do it ?

let's say I have 20 features in the Frame, now these features are just integers and I wanna put these features in A matrix in order to use them in the Matrix mentioned above

Comment: Your question is unclear. How's the input data formatted? Are you using a particular math package, or just 2d arrays?

Comment: @Kevin: he's using OpenCV (see tags)

Comment: @Paul: right, I'm using openCV.

Comment: @Kevin: I want to make a matrix contains these points to use them in a specific function

Comment: @Mario: if you're new to OpenCV then I recommend reading at least the first few chapters of the O'Reilly book "Learning OpenCV" - it covers the basics of the various OpenCV data structures, which you really need to understand if you're going to be doing stuff like this.

Comment: @Paul, thank you for the suggestion, I will do that. but how about what I needed for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on the example in [O'Reilly's Learning OpenCV](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130) on page 35-36:

```
float vals[] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };

CvMat mat;

cvInitMatHeader(&mat, 2, 2, CV_32FC1, vals);
```

This creates a 2x2 float Matrix using the statically allocated data above.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul, and I'll go with your suggestion about this book.